# Кодировка Хаффмана на с++

Tags: c++

Пытался сделать программу, которая кодировала бы заданные слова методом Хаффмана, но она работает не идеально. Если вводить всего 1 символ или не вводить вообще, кодирование не происходит. Буду благодарен, если поможете увидеть ошибку.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    int count;
    char symbol;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;

    Node() { }

    Node(char __symbol, int __count)
    {
        symbol = __symbol;
        count = __count;
    }

    Node(Node *l, Node *r) 
    {
        symbol = 0;
        left = l;
        right = r;
        count = l->count + r->count;
    }

    static void Print(Node *root, int depth = 0)
    {
        if (!root) return;

        if (root->symbol)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++)
                cout << ".";
            cout << root->symbol << endl;
        }
        else depth++;
        Print(root->left, depth);
        Print(root->right, depth);
    }
};

void BuildTable(Node *root, vector<bool> &code, map<char, vector<bool>> &table) 
{
    if (root->left)
    {
        code.push_back(0); 
        BuildTable(root->left, code, table);
    }

    if (root->right)
    {
        code.push_back(1); 
        BuildTable(root->right, code, table);
    }

    if (root->symbol)
        table[root->symbol] = code;
    if (code.size())
        code.pop_back();
}

bool SortNode(const Node *a, const Node *b)
{
    return a->count < b->count;
}

string Decode(string &str, map<vector<bool>, char> &table) 
{
    string out = "";
    vector<bool> code;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        code.push_back(str[i] == '0' ? false : true);
        if (table[code])
        {
            out += table[code];
            code.clear();
        }
    }
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter the text:" << endl;
    string raw;
    getline(cin,raw);
    map<char, int> symbols;

    for (int i = 0; i < raw.length(); i++)
        symbols[raw[i]]++;

    list<Node*> trees;
    map<char, int>::iterator itr;
    for (itr = symbols.begin(); itr != symbols.end(); itr++)
    {
        Node *p = new Node(itr->first, itr->second); 
        trees.push_back(p);
    }

        while (trees.size() != 1)

        {
            trees.sort(SortNode);

            Node *l = trees.front();
            trees.pop_front();
            Node *r = trees.front();
            trees.pop_front();

            Node *parent = new Node(l, r);
            trees.push_back(parent);
        }

    Node *root = trees.front();
    root->Print(root);

    vector<bool> code; 
    map<char, vector<bool> > table;
    BuildTable(root, code, table); 


    for (itr = symbols.begin(); itr != symbols.end(); itr++)
    {
        cout << itr->first << " - ";
        for (int j = 0; j < table[itr->first].size(); j++)
            cout << table[itr->first][j];
        cout << endl;
    }

    string out = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < raw.length(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < table[raw[i]].size(); j++)
        {
            out += table[raw[i]][j] + '0';
            cout << table[raw[i]][j];
        }
    cout << endl;
    cout << out.c_str() << endl;



    map<vector<bool>, char> ftable;
    for (auto i = table.begin(); i != table.end(); i++)
        ftable[i->second] = i->first;
    cout << Decode(out, ftable).c_str() << endl;


    while (true);
}
```

Comment: Отладчиком пробовали ходить?

Comment: @gbg Да, пробовал, но как исправить так и не понял, так как после моих правок программа не запускалась вовсе.

Comment: @Антон с отладкой у Вас не вышло.... отличная возможность повысить скилл отладки

Answer (score 2):

Мне удалось исправить код. Оставлю на будущее тем, кто столкнулись с похожей проблемой:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    int count;
    char symbol;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;

    Node() { }

    Node(char __symbol, int __count)
    {
        symbol = __symbol;
        count = __count;
    }

    Node(Node *l, Node *r) 
    {
        symbol = 0;
        left = l;
        right = r;
        count = l->count + r->count;
    }

    static void Print(Node *root, int depth = 0)
    {
        if (!root) return;

        if (root->symbol)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++)
                cout << ".";
            cout << root->symbol << endl;
        }
        else depth++;
        Print(root->left, depth);
        Print(root->right, depth);
    }
};

void BuildTable(Node *root, vector<bool> &code, map<char, vector<bool>> &table) 
{
    if (root->left)
    {
        code.push_back(0); 
        BuildTable(root->left, code, table);
    }

    if (root->right)
    {
        code.push_back(1); 
        BuildTable(root->right, code, table);
    }

    if (root->symbol)
        table[root->symbol] = code;
    if (code.size())
        code.pop_back();
}

bool SortNode(const Node *a, const Node *b)
{
    return a->count < b->count;
}

string Decode(string &str, map<vector<bool>, char> &table) 
{
    string out = "";
    vector<bool> code;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        code.push_back(str[i] == '0' ? false : true);
        if (table[code])
        {
            out += table[code];
            code.clear();
        }
    }
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    int a=0, c;
    cout << "Enter the text:" << endl;
    string raw;
    getline(cin,raw);
    map<char, int> symbols;

    for (int i = 0; i < raw.length(); i++)
        symbols[raw[i]]++;

    list<Node*> trees;
    map<char, int>::iterator itr;
    for (itr = symbols.begin(); itr != symbols.end(); itr++)
    {
        Node *p = new Node(itr->first, itr->second); 
        trees.push_back(p);
    }
    if (trees.size() == 0) {
        cout << "String is empty" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (trees.size() == 1) 
        {
            Node *root = trees.front();
            root->Print(root);
            cout << " - "<< a << endl;
            cout << a << endl;
            system("pause");
        }
        else
        {
            while (trees.size() != 1)

            {
                trees.sort(SortNode);

                Node *l = trees.front();
                trees.pop_front();
                Node *r = trees.front();
                trees.pop_front();

                Node *parent = new Node(l, r);
                trees.push_back(parent);
            }

            Node *root = trees.front();
            root->Print(root);

            vector<bool> code;
            map<char, vector<bool> > table;
            BuildTable(root, code, table);


            for (itr = symbols.begin(); itr != symbols.end(); itr++)
            {
                cout << itr->first << " - ";
                for (int j = 0; j < table[itr->first].size(); j++)
                    cout << table[itr->first][j];
                cout << endl;
            }

            string out = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < raw.length(); i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < table[raw[i]].size(); j++)
                {
                    out += table[raw[i]][j] + '0';
                    cout << table[raw[i]][j];
                }
            cout << endl;
            cout << out.c_str() << endl;



            map<vector<bool>, char> ftable;
            for (auto i = table.begin(); i != table.end(); i++)
                ftable[i->second] = i->first;
            cout << Decode(out, ftable).c_str() << endl;


            while (true);

            system("pause");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а как в этот алгоритм добавить сжатие файлов ??